# Talend Google BigQuery drop table via tRestClient

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

[tRestClient configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwuT0.png)

This is my first time with Google Cloud API, the idea is to drop a table using the API, I have surfed the documentation and tried every possible mean, the thing is I always get this error

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "authError",
"message": "Invalid Credentials",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
"code": 401,
"message": "Invalid Credentials"
```

which means my token is invalid yet I'm using the same token to insert data into `bigquery` via `tBigQueryInput` and it's working, can anyone help me or direct me where to look for answers.

Comment: Hi, confirm that the bearer token you are using is valid or not by running this command: `curl "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<YOUR-TOKEN>"`

Comment: I got this response
{
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
i guess i'm using the wrong token, but i'm using it to insert into BigQuery!

Comment: I was expecting other error message, so just to be sure, confirm that you have changed the whole `<YOUR-TOKEN>` with the value on the Bearer token field.
Also, as I don't know the tool you are using and you are just testing the API, try it directly from the [Google API Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/delete) and read about [authorizing API requests](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization)